# No stdlib in UNIX v7?

Tags: c, header-file, historical-unix

Browsing through the [v7 UNIX Sources](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc) I noticed there is no "stdlib" directory - further more using a v7 UNIX Emulator, there is no such file as `<stdlib.h>`. However functions like `exit()` and `malloc(), realloc(), free() .etc.` all exist in v7 UNIX. Also by `c89 (ANSI)` there was definitely a `<stdlib.h>` because it is present in `K&R ANSI Edition.` After hours of Google-ing I turn to SE :)

**So my question is:** When was `<stdlib.h>` first used officially in c? What is it's history (i.e. was it used by BSD, and then later included into `c89`?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The c89 standard would be the place to look; its [rationale](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/title.html) was published separately (and is not part of the standard). `stdlib.h` was a creation of the committee working on the standard rather than reflecting existing practice.  The [X3J11 rationale](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d10.html#-60stdlib-46h-62-4-10) says:

> The header `<stdlib.h>` was invented by the Committee to hold an assortment of functions that were otherwise homeless.

Old programs have ifdef's for the inclusion of `stdlib.h`, versus other places such as `memory.h` for `memcpy`, `malloc` and the like.

This does not say that until the standard was published, there *was* no `stdlib.h`.  For example, I have a note in one of my [header files](http://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html#download) stating that VMS 5.3 (released [June 1989](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/37927/Digital-VMS-Version-5-3-Release-Notes/)) had `stdlib.h`:

```
#if defined(vms)        /* VAX/VMS 5.3 */
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STDARG_H 1
#undef  HAVE_UNISTD_H
#define HAVE_OLD_TOKEN_SPLICE 1
#define HAVE_OLD_TOKEN_QUOTE  1
#endif
```

Rather, the companies which participated in the standard development incorporated these features as the standard progressed, so that when it *was* published, it reflected existing practice.

In the same header (and its history), I can see that SVr3 did not have `stdlib.h` (referring to Apollo's `svr5.5` environment), but that it appeared "later" (probably with SVr4, which was being developed around the same time as the c89 standard).

Regarding the point about BSDs, I can see that it appeared in 4.3reno in 1990 (too late to be relevant).  Likewise, it is easy to find comments that say SunOS 4 is pre-ANSI (although I recall an ANSI compiler added as an *option* fairly late in the process).  So let's disregard BSDs from a role as influences on this header, and leave it as the companies which were involved in the standard development.

For what it's worth, the rationale mentions trademarks of AT&T and Digital Equipment Corporation.